# How can I recognise an EF POCO proxy without referencing EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, poco

I need to spot EF POCO proxies; [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835846.aspx) gives some hints based around `ObjectContext.GetObjectType(type.GetType())`

However, I would really like to do this without the EF reference. For example, with NHibernate, I can check whether the object implements a marker interface, using the name (as a string) `"NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy"`.

Is there anything similar in EF POCO proxies? For example can I *rely* on them being in the namespace `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.`, or is that brittle?

Taking a peek inside reflector, it simply checks the assembly against internally tracked assemblies, which is problematic for me.

Comment: Depends on context, I think. If all your entity types come from one model assembly which you wrote, and runtime POCO proxies come from dynamic assemblies, you could look for entity types **not** defined in your model assembly.

Comment: @Craig as a library author I don't get to make assumptions, sadly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking under-the-hood, as an *implementation detail* it is indeed the case that in the current EF the type will always live in "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies". This probably isn't a robust test, but should change infrequently. I will attempt to clarify this with Microsoft, though.

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet that tests for this?

Answer (score 1):

I know a POCO proxy type named as this pattern, `UserDefinedName_123AF...`.

So how about this approach?

```
const string pattern = @"_[\dA-F]{64}\b";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
bool result = regex.IsMatch(tragetObject.GetType().Name);
```

Comment: The "hashed description"? (sha256 in 'X2' hex) True - and possibly useful *in combination* with the namespace.